# No previews in Outlook To-Do bar

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I’m using Outlook with the To-Do bar visible.  Until yesterday I could hover over a task and get a preview. For some reason that stopped.  It will show whatever’s in that column now.  For example if I hover over the due date of a task, the pop up window now just shows the same date information that’s already visible and nothing else.  I’ve tried everything I can think of in settings and can’t figure out how to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a detailed screenshot for explanation? Have you open the message preview?

[image]

Besides, the article compareing peer and to-do bar may help you.
https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/the-calendar-peek-in-outlook/